# SAS - Create a count which increases in every observation, but resets to zero based on the value of a binary variable

Tags: sas

I have a dataset which includes the following two variables (it includes more, but for simplicity's sake, I'll just discuss these two): Date and Hot

Date is a SAS date variable and Hot is a binary (0,1) variable.

I'd like to read the dataset and have a count variable which counts the number of days in a row where the Hot variable is a 1.

This is an example of what my data look like:

```
Date          Hot

14JUN2010     0
15JUN2010     1
16JUN2010     1
17JUN2010     0
18JUN2010     1
19JUN2010     1
20JUN2010     1
21JUN2010     0
```

This is an example of what I would like my data to look like:

```
Date          Hot    HotDays

14JUN2010     0      0
15JUN2010     1      1
16JUN2010     1      2
17JUN2010     0      0
18JUN2010     1      1
19JUN2010     1      2
20JUN2010     1      3
21JUN2010     0      0
```

I've tried a number of different things, none of which work. I've read up on the retain statement and group by processing, but I haven't figured out how to adapt those strategies to counting sequential dates by binary variable.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You should post what you've tried.  Retain is definitely a good approach- what didn't work when you tried it?  What's special about sequential dates here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take advantage of the values of HOT and process the data BY HOT NOTSORTED to detect when to reset the counter.

[Sum Statement](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lestmtsref/68024/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n1dfiqj146yi2cn1maeju9wo7ijs.htm)
[By Statement](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lestmtsref/68024/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p0yeyftk8ftuckn1o5qzy53284gz.htm)

```
data hot;
   input Date:date9. Hot;
   cards;
14JUN2010     0
15JUN2010     1
16JUN2010     1
17JUN2010     0
18JUN2010     1
19JUN2010     1
20JUN2010     1
21JUN2010     0
;;;;
   run;
data hotdays;
   set hot;
   by hot notsorted;
   if first.hot then hotdays=0;
   hotdays + hot;
   run;
```

[image]

Comment: I would suggest, given the nature of the question, it's probably worth explaining how `notsorted` and the `sum` operator work in the answer.  (That's also why I asked for clarification without giving an answer on an obviously easy question: knowing what the OP was doing wrong is essential here.)

Comment: Thanks! This worked. I didn't realize that notsorted was an option. This solution is perfect because it needed to be sorted by date, but the by statement needed to reference the hot variable.